# Can't start H2O cluster for manual Sparkling Water backend

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I'm trying to start a H2O cluster as external backend for Sparkling Water manually. By following the documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/sparkling-water/2.2/latest-stable/doc/deployment/backends.html#manual-mode-of-external-backend) it says I need to use the parameter 'name' with the extended H2O driver. But by doing so it says that the parameter 'name' doesn't exist. How can I set the cloud name so that I can use it to identify the cluster in the sparkling-shell? The help of the driver also doesn't mention a way to set the cloud name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

`java -cp $H2O_EXTENDED_JAR water.H2OApp -name test`

It looks like a bug in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you have extended h2o jar for h2odriver (with support for particular Hadoop), this h2odriver truly does not have `-name` argument. Instead, you need to use `-jobname` argument instead. We need to fix our documentation for this case.

If you are using the extended h2o driver for standalone h2o application, the `-name` argument should do the job.